# Run DTS packages against SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2000, dts

We have an old SQL server 2000 server hosting many DTS packages and all these packages were pushing data into a SQL Server 2005 database hosted on a different windows box. We are now planning to migrate this sql 2005 box to SQL server 2008r2. So, the dts packages would start dumping data into the new sql server 2008r2 server. With this scenario do we need to upgrade the DTS packages to SSIS or can we continue with existing setup and just push data from windows 2000 server (hosting DTS packages) to the SQL server 2008r2

Thanks

Comment: Why can you upgrade windows 2000 server + sql server 2000 as they are already Out of support ?

Comment: They want to do it as phase two ( 1yr down the line) and get rid for sql 2000 and windows 2000, but until then i m stuck with above scenario

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, its better to migrate to SSIS to have better support.

You have to use [DTS Package Migration Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768544%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) which ships with SQL Server 2008.

If you want to look at some 3rd party tools, then [DTS xChange](http://pragmaticworks.com/Products/DTS-xChange) is the best out in the market. Its costly - 20 Conversions for $900.